# Algorithm to perform nanometric image registration

Tags: python, image, opencv, scikit-image

I'm doing Full-Field optical coherence tomography (FFOCT) and I added a fluorescence measurement on my setup. I have 2 cameras, one recording the FFOCT signal and the other recording the Fluorescence signal. I tried to align my optical setup but it is impossible to achieve perfect pixel alignment (resolution is 300 nanometers here...).

So my idea was to register the fluorescence image onto the FFOCT image to be able to generate nice overlays. The problem is that it is not a rigid transformation, see following figure. What I mean here by rigid is correcting the translation, the rotation and the scaling (by iterating back and forth in the log-polar domain).

[Top left: FFOCT image - Top right: Fluorescence image - Bottom left: difference after registration - Bottom right: overlay.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA8fk.png)

My problem is that considering only rigid deformation, I can't achieve perfect pixel registration because of the different lenses aberrations in my setup. As a physicist, I would love to provide doctors with perfect pixel registration for overlays in order to make their life easier when it comes to understanding biological mechanisms. To reach my goal, I ordered this kind of distorsion target:

[Distorsion target with radial and grid shapes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deewx.png)

Now, what would be the best method to register such target knowing that I would like to end up with a dense vector field transformation to assign each pixel in the template image to the right position in the overlay image?

Thank you for helping me out !

Comment: I'd use Elastix or SimpleElastix (https://simpleelastix.readthedocs.io/NonRigidRegistration.html).  First do a rigid registration, then refine that with a spline registration or similar.  Example code for Elastix here: https://github.com/stefanv/ned_imagepairs (No ITK required.)